# MS Access date format when exporting to XML

Tags: xml, date, ms-access, export

Im trying export from access to xml. I have small problem it export date in format yyyy/mm/dd:T00:00:00.

How to export it in format without time? Or
Its posible to make new column with copy Date column just like text.

How to do it automatic? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after trying to format data in Access. I figured out it not posible, because export to xml using only raw data.

After all i used this transformation and it work well. 
YOu can use it in detail settings of export.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="parentElm">
        <xsl:value-of select="name(..)" />
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'DATUM'">
            <xsl:element name="DATUM">
                <xsl:call-template name="FormatDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="."/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="FormatDate">
    <xsl:param name="DateTime" />
    <xsl:variable name="date">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($DateTime,'T')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($date) != 10">
        <xsl:value-of select="$DateTime"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($date) = 10">
        <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your output query, instead of using the date field as is, use an expression:

```
Format([YourDateField], "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
```

Comment: Thank you. But i have no idea where is output query. I have different lang of access and its not translated corectly.

It posible make print screen? Where it shout be.

Im trying to export Report.

Comment: Its even posible modify this? Im trying everything ans Export is still same.
Export is Date/time. so I can change everything but export will be still same.

Comment: Then, in your report, set the format of a visible textbox to Standard and bind it to: =Format([YourDateField], "yyyy\/mm\/dd")    - move but keep the current textbox and set property Visible to No.

Comment: This code dont work for me. Its make error. Some thing like Missing operator, operand, or Invalid character, comma possibly text without quotation marks.

Even if it will work, is problem thath xml export dont export this column, it export olny source columns.

Comment: Well, then try with a semicolon: =Format([YourDateField]; "yyyy\/mm\/dd") ... or change your source column.

Comment: Thanks :) this works well. Nice so i have column with date data. And now it not posible to export created column with data, it looks like MS Access export just raw data :(

Comment: Thanks for help, i used transformation of DATE with XSL.